# Problems with finding π using Monte Carlo method in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, codeblocks, montecarlo

I have a program that is supposed to find an approximate of π using the Monte Carlo method, and the code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    double x=0, y=0, piEstimate=0, precision=0;
    int N;
    int nIn=0, nOut=0;
    std::cout << "Please enter the seed number." <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> N;
    for(int i=0;i<=N;i++){
        x=(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
        y=(double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
        if(sqrt(x*x+y*y)>1){
            nOut++;
        }else if(sqrt(x*x+y*y)<1){
            nIn++;
        }
    }
    piEstimate=4*(nOut/nIn);
    std::cout<<"The estimate of pi with "<<N<<" seeds is "<<4.0*(nOut/nIn)<<"."<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Error percentage at "<<abs(100.0-piEstimate/3.1415926)<<"."<<std::endl;
}
```

This, however, generates the following output, which seems unreasonable:
[image: montecarloprogramoutput]
What is the problem here, and why is the program generating such inaccurate numbers for π? I assume my logic fails somewhere in the middle, but I can't figure out where...
Running in Code::Blocks 16, C++0X standards.

Comment: You should call `std::srand()`exactly *once* at the start of your program to *seed* the random number generator. For something like this, usually using the current time is enough: `std::srand(std::time(0));`. For more accurate results you should consider using `<random>` features.

Comment: You don't need sqrt(). sqrt(v)<=1 if and only if v<=1. Won't fix the bug but will make you wrong faster!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The area of the quarter circle is

```
inside = (pi*r^2)/4
```

area of the quarter square is

```
total = r^2
```

and the area of the "outside"

```
outside = total - inside = r^2 - (pi*r^2)/4
```

So you got the formula wrong. You need to compare the total trials and the trials inside, not outside/inside:

```
4* inside / total  = pi
```

Btw when doing monte carlo and asking for precision you should not use `rand()` but the facilities you can find in `<random>`.

Comment: What is <rand>? Is it a library? I don't seem to see such a library.

Comment: @NamelessKing its part of the standard library since C++11. Its a bit more compilated to use than rand(), but when you need random numbers its completely worth taking a look at it

Comment: It's actually `<random>`.

Comment: @NamelessKing it doesnt really matter, as `rand()` is broken anyhow and your final result is supposed to be the same. If you want a different sequence of numbers each time you run the code, then yes you should seed it

Comment: @NamelessKing if you want to do it correctly you should output the seed to the console, as for monte carlo its important that you can reproduce exactly same result on a later run.

Comment: @tobi303: saying that `rand()` is "broken anyhow" is a bit too extreme, unless you refer to the fact that it's not thread-safe... LCGs do have their place as extremely fast PRNGs with decent output distributions. For a Montecarlo area calculation of a circle I don't think you'll get a significant difference from using a better PRNG.

Comment: @MatteoItalia afaik rand() has quite poor randomness. Calculating the circle is only an introductory example for monte carlo, there are faster and more accurate methods to estimate pi and nobody would use MC to do that. So even if it doesnt matter for the circle, imho one should take care to use the right tools already for the basic example